# Rails calling Models in the Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I have a migration that creates a table, and I need to access the model for that table to create another table. The migration seems to not recognized that the original table has been created, so to make sure I put a debugger in my code and when I get to the model call, it says `User(Table doesn't exist)` even though in mysql I see it being created.
Looks like migrations can't see the current state of the database, any ideas how to get around that?

Just to be more specific about my question:
I'm trying to use Archivist to create archive of my current User table so I have

```
class ArchivedHeuristicReviewsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table "users" do |t|
      t.string  "name"
      ...
    end
    debugger
    Archivist.update User
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
    drop_table :archived_users
  end
end
```

the Archivist, doesn't create the archived_user table, so when I stopped at debugger and did User, I got `User(Table doesn't exist)`.

I even tried Archivist call in a newer migration, so to make sure User creation is all done, but it still didn't recognize the user table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why dont you write a rake task to call the function?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
User.connection.schema_cache.clear!
User.reset_column_information
```

Comment: It didn't. it still thinks User table doesn't exist.